# access control-allow origin error only in android but not when running in browser

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova

I am building an phonegap app for android using anguarJS for the front end and PHP(slim framework). The api is hosted on different server so basically it is cross site xhr request. I put the access-control header as * in both php and htaccess, but I received multiple header error so I removed it from php.

When I run the angular app in browser, It don't throw any CORS error, But when I built this into phonegap app it is throwing access control header not present error. I checked this error via ripple emulator. But the header is present and I can see it when running as an angular app.

what could be the problem.? Please help me on this issue..

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size,X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since,X-File-Name, Cache-Control, x-hash-key, x-req-timestamp, user-language-pref, Content_Language");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start();
require('vendor/autoload.php');
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array());

// fixing angular options request problem
$app->map('/:x+', function($x) {
    http_response_code(200);
})->via('OPTIONS');

// route definitions 

$app->run();
```

this is the very first line of my back end code. So I think something must be wrong in the front end.

Comment: @shammon I updated the question with the code

Comment: don't search for the allow origin header I put that in .htaccess "Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"" like this, now again replaced that to php.

Comment: Add the cordova whitelist plugin and try again.https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: yeah I did, What I found on debugging is get requests are working, they are receiving the required CORS headers, but not post requests. They are  only having problems.

Comment: It was problem with ripple's remote proxy, I forgot to disable it. Now everything is fine. Such a waste of time. thanks for speding your time anyway @shammon